# C# - SerialPort.ReadLine() freezes my program

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, readline

I'm trying to read messages sent form my Arduino over a Serial port using baud rate 9600.

My Arduino code is programmed to send a "1" whenever I press a button and a "0" when I release my finger off the button.

So it's not constantly sending data.

My C# Program is to read that message and add it to a ListBox. But whenever I start it, the program hangs.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
    port.BaudRate = 9600;
    port.PortName = "COM4";
    port.ReadTimeout = 1000;
    port.Open();


    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ee = port.ReadLine();
        listBox1.Items.Add(ee);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

I guess, maybe the reason is that my program should check if there's data available to be received before receiving?

Comment: `ReadLine` reads until there is line terminator (`\n`) in stream. From your description it seems like your device never outputs such terminator, so `ReadLine` blocks forever.

Comment: Use of `ReadLine` from stream devices (like serial port) is not a good idea, exactly because it freezes the program *(when there is no finished 'line', or no data at all)*. Use `DataReceived` event to ensure there are data and `ReadExisting` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this instead. It will at least not hang, and then you can sort out what sort of data your are getting via `DataReceived`

From there you can determine how to better write your app

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
    port.BaudRate = 9600;
    port.PortName = "COM4";
    port.ReadTimeout = 1000;

   // Attach a method to be called when there
   // is data waiting in the port's buffer
   port.DataReceived += new
      SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

   // Begin communications
   port.Open();
}

private void port_DataReceived(object sender,
                                 SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer in the output window
   Debug.WriteLine("data : " + port.ReadExisting());
}
```

[SerialPort.DataReceived Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Indicates that data has been received through a port represented by
>   the SerialPort object.

[SerialPort.ReadExisting Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Reads all immediately available bytes, based on the encoding, in both
>   the stream and the input buffer of the SerialPort object.

Comment: Thanks!! this really helped!

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this problem, you need to add **"\n"** to your data in your arduino because
port.ReadLine(); search for ending line **("\n")**

For example, let's say that the data which arduino sends is **"1"**, to read this data with port.ReadLine(); it should be **"1\n"**

Also, do not worry, port.ReadLine(); **doesn't read "\n"**. Just stops there when it sees "\n".

I hope it helps.